# Image Property in asp:Repeater accessing through FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `asp:repeater` and in the repeater I have an `asp:image`. Now I want to access the image through a find control and put image in it. This is my code so far. I tried but not succeeded.
I also have tried this code in another place in a gridview where it's working fine.

```
    clsFileUpload fileUpload = new clsFileUpload();
    dataTable = fileUpload.GetDownloadsFiles(ClsSystemUsers.ProgramId, ClsSystemUsers.SemesterN, 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //rptLec is my repeater id...
        rptLec.DataSource = dataTable;
        rptLec.DataBind();
        string label = dt.Rows[i]["Url"].ToString();
        Image = (Image)rptLec.FindControl("Image_Video");

        if (label != null)
        {
            string turl = label;
            GetYouTubeImage(turl);//function for getting image from youtube
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use (If you used `<ItemTemplate>)`:

```
rptLec.Items[0].FindControl("Image_Video");
```

Also you can bind your `datatable` to your `repeater` outside of `for` loop.

So try  changing your code like this:

```
clsFileUpload fileUpload = new clsFileUpload();
dataTable = fileUpload.GetDownloadsFiles(ClsSystemUsers.ProgramId, ClsSystemUsers.SemesterN, 3);
//rptLec is my repeater id...
rptLec.DataSource = dataTable;
rptLec.DataBind();

for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
        string label = dt.Rows[i]["Url"].ToString();
        Image = (Image)rptLec.Items[0].FindControl("Image_Video");      
        if (label != null)
        {
            string turl = label;
            GetYouTubeImage(turl);//function for getting image from youtube
        }
}
```